# Updating heatmap data, simple google HeatMap

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, heatmap

I've built this android app to collect longitude,latitude, and phone signals for my class project. My objective is to port this info to a simple heatmap webpage. My question is what's the best way to update my heatmap data variable in this example:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

This variable in particular:

```
      var taxiData = [
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
          new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586), ...
          ];
```

I'm open to all suggestions, I'm pretty much a novice with web development.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Google maps makes this very straightforward. You might notice later on in this example, taxiData is loaded into a specific google array here -

```
 pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);
```

And then this is put into the map as a heatmap here:

```
heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: pointArray
});
heatmap.setMap(map);
```

The MVCArray can be updated, and the map will automatically update. So, if you need to add a new LatLng to your heatmap, simply put:

```
pointArray.push(new LatLng(<coordinates>));
```

And the map will update.

Comment: thanks man, didn't realize MVCArrays work like that! This points me in a good direction, I think I'm gonna do some more JS tutorials, literally started with it today.

Comment: is it also possible to change the weight or latlon properties of existing points in the heatmap? For an animation I want the changes in the heatmap to be as fluently as possible. Right now I am clearing the heatmap layer by setting the map to null and then set a layer with all new data to the map but that results in not seeing any heatmap points for a short time

Comment: @DanielvanDommele A `LatLng` can't be updated, you have to replace whatever data you're manipulating. It's still relatively easy with this: if you have an variable `oldLatLng` that you're replacing with `newLatLng', the code to do it is `pointArray.setAt(pointArray.indexOf(oldLatLng), newLatLng)`. I can't say specifically if this will work well in your case, if you want a more thorough review of your problem you should probably open a new question.

Comment: hmm I don't think that would improve much in my case... yet I will try it. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Thanks a million. This is just what i need.