# Updating existing heatmap in Google Maps API V3 giving TypeError: g[b.x] is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, websocket

I have the following code, which will load the map fine first go, however, any further "runHeatmap()" calls error:

**This is the error from Firbug (firefox):**

TypeError: g[b.x] is undefined

https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/14/0/%7Bmain,visualization%7D.js/eval/seq/6

Line 3

**This is the error from Chrome:**

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined

(anonymous function)

H.forEach %7Bmain,visualization%7D.js:28

EQ

TQ

H.aa

(anonymous function) %7Bmain,visualization%7D.js:34

**The code:**

```
var map = null, heatmap = null, heatmapData = [];

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(20, 12),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
});

function runHeatmap() {
    var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(heatmapData);
    if (!heatmap) {
        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray,
            map: map
        });
    } else {
        heatmap.setData(pointArray);
    }
}

//receives [["34.3565","-29.23434"],["-3.4857","64.3984"]]
socket.on('coordArr', function(d){
    if (d.length > 0) {
        var i=0;
        while(i < d.length) {
            var lat = d[i][0].trim();
            var lng = d[i][1].trim();
            heatmapData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
            i++;
        }
        runHeatmap();
    }
});

//receives ["-8.284374","94.2837"]
socket.on('coord', function (d) {
    var lat = d[0].trim();
    var lng = d[1].trim();
    heatmapData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
    runHeatmap();
});
```

1. The google map with satellite loads fine.
2. When the socket is opened the browser receives 'coordArr' event and that data pushes properly and generates the heatmap looking like this:
   [image]
3. The socket then receives the 'coord' event and the correct data when that function calls "runHeatmap();" it causes the error.

Should I be destroying the heatmap and re-writing it? It seems rather resource wasteful, am I just using the wrong method for updating an existing heatmap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle between data in Google Heat Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847944/toggle-between-data-in-google-heat-map)

Comment: That explains how to do what I'm already doing, just more simplistically. I am getting an actual error from the API caused by something unknown within the process of re-applying the pointArray to the heatmap post-creation. I had already read the question.

Comment: With the posted code and responses the error should not occur. Please check the socket-responses, this error appears to happen because of an invalid value of a LatLng in heatMapData.(check if the arguments provided to coordArr and coord have the desired structure)

Comment: @Dr.Molle Want to put an answer saying that error is a result of invalid lat/long values? The socket response wasn't an array it was a JSON string of an array (they look the same console.log'd - unless you click on log'd item). Thanks for making me re-look. Answer and I'll make sure to mark your answer.